# img property global style taking effect

Tags: css

my css file has a property (see below) that applies to all images:

```
img{height:auto;max-width:100%;}
```

I have images in a particular div that I don't want to apply this to.
I can assign a new image class but the global one above still takes effect.

Is there a way to prevent the global img applying to images within this div?

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

use the !important property on your new image class.

```
.auto-width {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

Also, CSS files are cascading so if you put your new image class after the standard image class, you will be able to override the max-width without the !important statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you make more specific your rule then it be primordial like:

```
div.contenedor img {
  height:10%;
  max-width:50%;
}
```

Also set this after the other rule.

*You need to change all the previous properties*

Answer (score 0):

You want to reset the properties to their defaults. `height: auto` is the default anyway, so the only one you need to get rid of is `max-width`, which you need to set to `none`.

```
div.auto-width img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Because this selector has greater specificity (`0021` vs `0010`) it overrides the original definition.